# Find High CPU Processes in Azure Log Analytics

Tags: azure

I have created the following alert in Log Analytics. The alert is designed to get all computers where the _Total CPU usage was over 90% in the last ten minutes. However, when I run the alert I get the error:

'join' operator: Failed to resolve table or column expression named 'FindCPU'

Can someone let me know what might be required to fix this issue?

```
//Find Top processes utilizing CPU
// by finding the machine(s) using over 90% of CPU
// then finding the processes using the CPU
// also finding CPU count of the machines to find the actual percentage of CPU being used

//defining our CPU threshold
let CPUThreshold = 90;

//define time sample rate
let Time = 10m;

//define Count of processes to return
let Count = 5;

//Find instances of total cpu being used above 90% over the last 10 minutes
let TopCPU = Perf
| where TimeGenerated > now(-Time)
              and ObjectName == "Processor"
              and CounterName == "% Processor Time"
              and InstanceName == "_Total"
              and CounterValue > CPUThreshold
| project Computer, ObjectName
              , CounterName, CounterValue
              , TimeGenerated;
//end query

// find top Processes, excluding _Total and Idle instances, there may be other instances you want to exclude as well
let TopProcess = Perf
| where TimeGenerated > now(-Time)
               and CounterName == "% Processor Time"
               and InstanceName != "_Total"
               and InstanceName != "Idle"
| project Computer, ObjectName
              , CounterName, InstanceName
              , CounterValue, TimeGenerated;
// end query

// find CPU count for servers(s)
let FindCPU = Perf
| where TimeGenerated >= ago(1h)
| where ObjectName == "Processor"
              and CounterName == "% Processor Time"
              and InstanceName!="_Total"
| sort by InstanceName asc nulls first
| summarize CPUCount = dcount(InstanceName) by Computer;
// end query

//Join all 3 datasets together
FindCPU | join(TopCPU) on Computer 
| join(TopProcess)on Computer
| extend PercentProcessorUsed = CounterValue1 / CPUCount
| summarize avg(PercentProcessorUsed) by Computer, ObjectName
                  , CounterName, CPUCount 
                  , TotalCPU=CounterValue //rename CounterValue to TotalCPU 
                  , Process=ObjectName1 //rename ObjectName1 to Process 
                  , ProcessTime=CounterName1 //rename CounterName1 to ProcessTime 
                  , ProcessName=InstanceName //rename InstanceName to ProcessName 
                  , TimeGenerated
| where Process == "Process"
and avg_PercentProcessorUsed > 25 // only return processes that are using more than 25%
| top Count by avg_PercentProcessorUsed desc
| project Computer, CPUCount
                , ProcessName , avg_PercentProcessorUsed
                , TotalCPU, Process
                , ProcessTime, TimeGenerated
```

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The query runs fine (although seems a bit over complicated for what you are trying to do), however, you need to make sure that you select all of the queries when you run it.

By default, if your cursor is at the end of all the queries, Log Analytics will only run the last query, which obviously errors because it cannot find "FindCPU". Highlight everything, then run it and it works fine.